# Getting Sum of milligram, grams, and kilograms in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I use data types decimal(10,3) and now I try to get SUM of all column, and it will return depends on what is the SUM of all units.

E.g.:

```
0.789 mg
98.057 g
5.008 kg
```

The query are automatically calculate this, but how?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUM(prod_name,'-',prod_quantity,' ',
    CASE WHEN prod_unit = 'mg' THEN 'g' 
         ELSE prod_unit 
    END)) AS shortName 
FROM prod_table;
```

The answer is wrong, and I don't know what is the formula on adding mass or volume.

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: You should probably store all items in the weight of the lowest common denominator. In your case, that would be all products in `mg`. So an item that weighs 5.008 kg would have a weight value of 5008000 (equal to the product's weight in mg). When you want to display a product's weight, it's easy to convert `5008000` to `"5.008 kg"` with a simple function. This would make many things much easier for you. For example you could easily sort by weight or sum many items' weight without the need for pre-converting the units. **Short answer:** fix the way you store the data and your problem goes away.

Comment: Or as another example, this is more easily seen with something like a product price. Prices (as one example) can be made up dollars and cents. It would be silly to store some products with a cents value and others with a dollars value. Represent all products in cents (`INT` type) or all products in dollars (`DECIMAL` type). Make a choice and make it consistent. That is the most important part.

Comment: I'd also strongly encourage you to store these in a common unit to avoid the crippling mess that is mixing up units by accident. This has a very high chance of malfunctioning and someone thinking they're transporting 10kg of materials when in fact it's ten tons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this question. First, you should add the weights properly, which means adding them all after converting them to the same units. To avoid losing precision, let's add them in milligrams:

```
SELECT SUM(prod_quantity * CASE prod_unit WHEN 'mg' THEN 1
                                          WHEN 'g'  THEN 1000
                                          WHEN 'kg' THEN 1000000
                           END) sum_milligrams
FROM   prod_table;
```

This will give the results in milligrams. Now, we can handle beautifying the output by deciding in which units to display it. For example, we could decide that anything weighing 1 kg or more would be displayed in kg, anything between 1 gr and 1 kg would be displayed in grams and anything less than that would be displayed in milligrams:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s > 1000000 THEN CONCAT(s/1000000.0, ' kg')
            WHEN s BETWEEN 1000 AND 1000000 THEN CONCAT(s/1000, ' g')
            ELSE CONCAT(s, ' mg')
       END
FROM   (SELECT SUM(prod_quantity * CASE prod_unit WHEN 'mg' THEN 1
                                                  WHEN 'g'  THEN 1000
                                                  WHEN 'kg' THEN 1000000
                                   END AS s
        FROM   prod_table) t;
```

Comment: So, I need to do is to change my datatype to decimal(10,2) ? I am right ?

Comment: @ArnoldZurbito what do you think so?

Comment: @ArnoldZurbito, as a user of ~100K reputation, can you please educate newbie users instead of giving them spaghetti SQL to allow his/her bad schemas to continue existing ? I know it's harder to actually educate someone, but please make the effort.

Comment: @naomik I disagree with your analysis, and you've presented opinion as fact. I think this schema is more or less ok. The OP should consider storing units in a separate table, along with their conversion factors. Then the solution would involve a simple join.

Comment: It is not an opinion that the SQL provided here is a spaghetti mess.